# How to execute the Water-Detect Python package for remote sensing

Tags: python, git, pip, computer-vision

I am trying to use the WaterDetect Python package available at https://github.com/cordmaur/WaterDetect to detect water in satellite images. I have installed the package using pip and also cloned the git repository to my local machine.

However, when I try to run the package using either the run_batch() function or the command line interface !waterdetect -i input_folder -o output_folder, I am getting an error message. I have followed the instructions in the package readme, but it does not provide much help.

I have also tried running the demo Jupyter notebook provided in the repository, but it seems to be outdated as well.

Here's the code I am using:

```
import waterdetect as wd
input_folder = "path/to/input/folder"
output_folder = "path/to/output/folder"
wd.DWWaterDetect.run_batch(input_folder=input_folder, output_folder=output_folder)
```

And the command line code:

```
!waterdetect -i input_folder -o output_folder
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 wd.DWWaterDetect.run_batch(input_folder=input_folder,
      2                            output_folder=output_folder                          )

AttributeError: type object 'DWWaterDetect' has no attribute 'run_batch'
```

Can someone help me with this error and suggest how to properly use the WaterDetect package to detect water in satellite images? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO can't help. bug report is all you can do: https://github.com/cordmaur/WaterDetect/issues/25 -- their readme says `run_batch` but github shows me no results in actual code. clearly their repo needs a little work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the cross-posts, Christoph. In the future Souvik, you should post links to each related post and issue report in each and all places you file them. That saves folks trying to answer your question wasting time on saying the same thing already stated elsewhere. And In the end it helps those following in your footsteps actually find the solution (hopefully) and not a dead end in one spot, whereas the solution was posted at some other unlinked location. Importantly, the person following your footsteps may be yourself months from now, and so it could help you in the end.

Comment: @Wayne That issue was created by me only.

Comment: Yes, @SouvikDatta but Christoph nicely linked the cross-postings which you failed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `run_single` and the `.run_batch` methods mentioned in the docs were replaced by `.run_water_detect` with a mandatory attribute called `single_mode: bool` to achieve the same result (single or multiple image processing).

The `read.me` was adjusted accordingly.

The regular usage as a script remains the same, e.g.:

```
waterdetect -i c:/input_folder -o -c:/output_folder -p S2_THEIA
```

To call it from a notebook on a single image:

```
from waterdetect import DWWaterDetect

DWWaterDetect.run_water_detect(
    input_folder=images/'S2A_MSIL2A_20190302T134211_N0211_R124_T22KDV_20190302T174619.SAFE',
    output_folder=home/'Projects/data/images',
    single_mode=True,
    product='S2_S2COR',
    config_file=home/'Projects/WaterDetect.ini',
)
```

or, for multiple images:

```
from waterdetect import DWWaterDetect

DWWaterDetect.run_water_detect(
    input_folder=images,
    output_folder=home/'Projects/data/images',
    single_mode=False,
    product='S2_S2COR',
    config_file=home/'Projects/WaterDetect.ini',
)
```

Here is the full signature:

```
DWWaterDetect.run_water_detect?

Signature:
DWWaterDetect.run_water_detect(
    input_folder,
    output_folder,
    single_mode,
    shape_file=None,
    product='S2_THEIA',
    config_file=None,
    pekel=None,
    post_callback=None,
    **kwargs,
)
Docstring:
Main function to launch the water detect algorithm processing. This is the function called from the script.
@param input_folder: If single_mode=True, this is the uncompressed image product. If single_mode=False, this
is the folder that contains all uncompressed images.
@param output_folder: Output directory
@param single_mode: For batch processing (multiple images at a time), single_mode should be set to False
@param shape_file: Shape file to clip the image (optional).
@param product: The product to be processed (S2_THEIA, L8_USGS, S2_L1C or S2_S2COR)
@param config_file: Configuration .ini file. If not specified WaterDetect.ini from current dir and used as
                    default
@param pekel: Optional path for an occurrence base map like Pekel
@param post_callback: Used for the WaterQuality add-on package
@param kwargs: Additional parameters.
@return: DWWaterDetect instance with the generated mask.
File:      ~/miniconda3/envs/waterdetect/lib/python3.8/site-packages/waterdetect/WaterDetect.py
Type:      method
```